# Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD python

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to convert

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH_MM_SS
```

to

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
i=0
var="2016-05-03"
while i < 5
new_date = datetime.strptime(var, "%Y-%m-%d") + relativedelta(days=i)
i=i+1
print(new_date)
```

in this example I would like to convert new_date to string YYYY-MM-DD. I have tried many option, none of them worked...

I thought it will be quite easy but it is not, how to handle with that ?

Comment: If you just want to cut off the time, wouldn't `var[:10]` be sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

just change the print statement

```
print(new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```